# phpmyadmin multiple accounts for one database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I was wondering if it was possible to have 1 database, but multiple logins (so that when a developer leaves, we don't have to change the entire db password and all instances of it).

If that's possible, how would I do it? (I have NO experience with phpmyadmin aside from code related queries, I'm doing research for a friend who would be able to implement it)

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Realistically, shouldn't the db password only be stored in one place and just accessed (included) repeatedly? If that dev leaves, you can change the pw from the server, change the password in the dbconnect file and voila!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin has a simple way of creating new SQL users. From the home screen, click on the database in the left column for which you want to add a new user. Click on the Privileges tab. At the bottom, there is a command labeled, "Add new user"; click that. Type in the username and password that you want to assign to the account. To restrict the user to that database, select "Grant all privileges on database."

Note: I'm using phpMyAdmin 3.4.7.1.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html for a the SQL queries to create new users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite simple. PhpMyAdmin validates logins against MySQL's user permissions list. Simply create multiple MySQL users with full privileges on the DB in question and give each admin their own user.

It's easy to set this up from directly inside PhpMyAdmin. Just log in as a high-privilege user and click the "Privileges" tab. Then "Add New User" and specify the username, the host (generally `localhost`), a password and then create the user (with no privileges checked). Once the user is created, go back to the user list on the Privileges tab and click the edit button next to your new user. Then, under "Database-specific privileges", select the database you'd like to grant privileges... then just select all the rights you want to give this user and click "Go". This new MySQL user and password can now be issued to an admin so he/she can log into PhpMyAdmin, and it revoked at any time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible. If you are using localhost, just login and create a new user and give the privileges for the database.

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management#Creating_a_new_user

If you are hosted server on Linux, there is an option to create new users and and assign to the databases with different privileges.